# Unable to upload the image with MultipartFormDataContent C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, httpclient

I have the requirement to upload a certain image to the server with help of API. But, it always failed with a bad request/not acceptable error message. But, I can able to upload the same image with the postman. Here, I will attach both the result.

Postman Auto generated code :

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:3000/api/calendar/thumb/photo");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xjmwn4WL5H_3VsfhdsghdsKHGFQ-L-gjAmoN");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "__profilin=p%3Dt");
request.AddFile("image[file]", "/C:/Users/antony/Desktop/Avatar.jpg");
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The content received on the server-side while posting through the postman,

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"image"=><ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fffd55f0af0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210401-10712-x81lh3.jpg>, @original_filename="Avatar.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[file]\"; filename=\"Avatar.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: false>, "Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data", "controller"=>"calendar", "action"=>"upload_photo_api"} permitted: false>
```

The above one was working perfectly.

And, I have written a similar kind of code in my c# application. I have used the below function to upload the photo.

```
private async Task<bool> uploadPhoto(string email, string data, string hash) {

    byte[] photo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(photo, 0, photo.Count());
    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
        FileName = string.Concat(email, "_", hash, ".jpg"),
        Name = "image[file]",
    };

    MultipartFormDataContent postContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    postContent.Add(content);
    Httpwrapper service = cService.ConfigureServices().GetRequiredService<Httpwrapper>();

    string apiRes = await service.SendAsync("api/calendar/thumb/photo", postContent, HttpMethod.Post);
    return apiRes != string.Empty;
}
```

And, my httpClient as like below

```
HttpClient client;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xjmwn4WL5H_3VsfhdsghdsKHGFQ-L-gjAmoN");
```

This code sends the data to the server as like below,

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"image"=><ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f0e04ee4530 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210402-10712-tuf0rm.jpg>, @original_filename="anton@testdomain.com_58-A0-7F-41-58-09-13-06-8D-3E-48-77-73-39-08-AD.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"anton@testdomain.com_58-A0-7F-41-58-09-13-06-8D-3E-48-77-73-39-08-AD.jpg\"; name=\"image[file]\"\r\n">} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"calendar", "action"=>"upload_photo_api"} permitted: false>
```

But, This does not work and it's through the error message bad_request or not_acceptable.

I see the **"Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data"** was the only difference between both the request. The request send through the postman has the **"Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data"** and the request send through the code does not have that **"Content-Type"=>"multipart/form-data"**. But, I'm not sure how to include that.

What am I missing?